# html / php code validation error

Tags: php, html

I keep getting errors while trying to validate this code.

Error message examples:

```
e.g. 1 - Line 152, Column 42: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values  …>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Name); ?>"…

e.g. 2 - Line 152, Column 42: attributes construct error  …>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Name); ?>"…


e.g. 3 - Line 152, Column 42: Couldn't find end of Start Tag input line 152  …>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Name); ?>"…
```

The same errors occur for any lines that contains the line e.g < php echo htmlspecialchars($...)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
<!-- Form-->
<form name="editcontact" method="post" action=""> 

<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<caption>Edit Contact</caption>

<!--ID Input-->
<tr><td><?php if ($ContactID != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="ContactID" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ContactID); ?>" />
<?php } ?></td></tr>



<!--Name Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Name">Name</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Name); ?>" size="30" maxlength="50" tabindex="1"/></td>
</tr>

<!-- Address Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Address">Address</label></td>
<td><textarea name="Address" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($Address); ?> </textarea></td>
</tr>

<!--Phone Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Phone">Phone</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Phone" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Phone); ?>" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="3" /> </td>
</tr>

<!--Mobile Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Mobile">Mobile</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Mobile" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Mobile); ?>"  size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="4" /> </td>
</tr>

<!--Email Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Email">Email</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email" value= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Email); ?>" size="30" maxlength="50" tabindex="5" /></td>
</tr>

<!--Submit Button-->
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()" tabindex="6"/>      
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your labels are useless. The for attribute has to match the **id** of the form control, not the name.

Comment: You might want to look at getting a better validator. I don't think `<` characters are forbidden in attribute values in any version of HTML (although I think PIs (`<?`) are)).

Comment: could you suggest a validator? I was just using http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: huh, it's usually pretty reliable, maybe I'm wrong. What Doctype are you using?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: huh, seems XML does forbid unescaped `<` in attribute values.

Answer (score 4):

Run the PHP and validate the HTML output. Don't try to validate PHP as if it was HTML.

Comment: oh ok, I had ran the validation for pages that contain only php and they return valid so does it just not like it when they contain php and html?

Comment: Probably you're validating HTML. You first have to run your server side PHP code and validate the output(HTML)

Comment: It is possible to write PHP syntax that conforms to HTML syntax (there are places in HTML where PIs are allowed). The example you gave is just one that does not. Trying to validate PHP as HTML is pointless though.